# PHP can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have been thrown into the world of PHP, and I'm having a bit of an issue connecting to my SQL server.  I'm using the following code to try to connect.  When it hits the SQLsrv_connect command, it just seems to stop processing.  No error, it just stops loading.

```
function testConnection()
{
    $returnable = "TEST";

    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"MyDatabase", "UID"=>"MyLogin", "PWD"=>"MyPassword");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect("MyServer",$connectionInfo);
    if ($conn) {
       echo "Connection Established.<br />";
    } else {
       echo "Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL.<br />";
    }

     return $returnable;
}
```

Any idea on what I might be missing?  I tried some very old syntax for version 5, and I got the same issue.  I am trying to connect to sql server 2008.

Thanks

Comment: How do you connect to the database normally? Is it with Windows based authentication or do you use a username and password?

Comment: SQL authentication

Comment: It stops processing or does it echo anything?

Comment: It just stops processing.  any echoes before will be displayed, but if I try putting one after, it will not be displayed.

Comment: So the if logic doesn't do anything

Comment: is MyServer the local machine or in the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you have installed the sql_srv extension for PHP.
Probably this extension is not installed/loaded by you php.ini file.

**For Windows**

Download proper driver from [SQL Driver for MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver) extract and copy into you php installation directory. Then edit php.ini file and add in extensions path your extension. (For 99% you should copy NTS sql_srv version) also don't forget add sql_srv_pdo extension.

**For Ubuntu/Linux**
You can try install sql_srv and pdo_sql_srv by pecl (if is installed)
`pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv`.

Comment: I did find this issue on my local machine, and was able to get it working (I have php 7.0).  However, now I am trying it on my dev server, and the connection test works fine, however, the exact same code won't work.